# The boundary of this set is smooth?

Tags: general-topology, partial-differential-equations, differential-topology

Let $\Omega_1 \supset \Omega_2 \supset....$ a decreasing sequence of bounded, convex and smooth sets.

My intuition says that the set $int(\overline{\bigcap_i \Omega_i})$ (where int denotes the interior of a set) has smooth boundary. I dont know how to prove or disprove this ...

Someone can give me a help ?

thanks in advance !

Comment: When you say smooth, how smooth should it be? $C^\infty$, $C^n$, Lipschitz,  cone condition, segment condition? Please be more specific.

Comment: @Yiorgos S. Smyrlis , smooth = $C^{\infty}$. Sorry to not say this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intersection of your sets might be any convex set. In particular it might be a square, which is not smooth.

To get a square consider 
$$
\Omega_i = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2 \colon f_i(x,y) < 0\}
$$
where 
$$
f_i(x,y) = (|x|^i + |y|^i)^{\frac 1 i}. 
$$